# Win32 DLL #pragma linke Export Forwards, results in unresolved symbol while linking

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, win32-process, cl.exe

I have 2 dlls test_dll1.c and test_dll2.c.
test_dll2 should act as a proxy to test_dll1.
I also have a main program test.c, which links with test_dll2.lib, but the linker gives out an error saying "unresolved symbol", which I'm unsure why.

Below is the code attached

test_dll1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void dummy1(void)
{
    printf("Inside %s %s\n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__);

    return;
}

 __declspec(dllexport) void dummy2(void)
{
    printf("Inside %s %s\n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__);

    return;
}
```

cl.exe /LD test_dll1.c

test_dll2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(linker, "/export:dummy3=test_dll1.dummy1")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:dummy4=test_dll1.dummy2")
```

cl.exe /LD test_dll2.c
test_forwards.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

__declspec(dllimport) void dummy3(void);
__declspec(dllimport) void dummy4(void);

int main()
{
    dummy3();
    dummy4();
 }
```

$ cl.exe test_forwards.c test_dll2.lib

test_forwards.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__dummy3 referenced in function _main
test_forwards.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__dummy4 referenced in function _main
test_forwards.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

What am I missing?  Why isn't the linker able to find the symbols?  dummy3 and dummy4 are defined as forwarded exports in "test_dll2.dll" as I can see that if I dump the exports in test_dll2.dll, so the exported symbols dummy3 and dummy4 do exist.

Update:
Btw I updated my test_dll2.c to
    #pragma comment(linker, "/export:_dummy3=test_dll1.dummy1")
    #pragma comment(linker, "/export:_dummy4=test_dll1.dummy2")

Where I changed dummy3 and dummy4  to _dummy3 and _dummy4 and it worked.  Why do I need to change the symbol name to _dummy3 and _dummy4?

Comment: The /export directive is wrong and should have produced a linker error.  So it isn't being used at all, it is unclear what "test_forwards.c" could possibly be.  A proper one uses the decorated symbols so should be "/export:_dummy3=_dummy1"

Comment: Unsure if I used it wrongly. I was following many of the articles google threw at me.  One such example https://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S202B.aspx  The test_forwards.c is a dummy program that calls dummy3() from test_dll2.c.  Basically what I am doing is having test_dll2.dll forward calls to test_dll1.c and test_forwards.c is the main program i have written to test this, which calls dummy3() from test_dll2.dll, which I expected would forward it to dummy1 from test_dll1.dll

Comment: Btw, in my original example, where I have used /export I can see it is used by the linker, since if I dump the pe header export direectory of test_dll2.dll, I can see this(formatted by me) - "dummy4 (Forwarded to test_dll1._dummy2)"

Comment: @HansPassant Btw, I tried what you suggest i.e. /export:_dummy3=_dummy1 and that doesn't work.  Anyways what I am trying to do is forward to dummy1 located in test_dll1.  Shouldn't that be test_dll2.dummy1?  Either ways none of these things I tried work.

Comment: We still don't really know what test_forwards.c is, but if it tries to call dummy3 then the /export directives are in the wrong place.  The pragmas must appear in the source code files that are used to build the DLL.  They are useless in code that uses the DLL, that code doesn't export anything.  So a proper build command for the DLL should resemble cl.exe /LD test_dll1.c test_dll2.c.  Now the #pragmas do their job.  Renaming the exports in the client code is not possible.

Comment: @HansPassant The pragmas are indeed present in the source code files that are  used to build the DLL and not in code that uses the DLL.  Check test_dll2.c above.